# How to determine the PDF of the chi distribution using the Jacobian formula?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

The Question is:

> Assume $X$ has the $\chi^2$ distribution ("chi-squared") with $n$ degrees of freedom. What is the distribution of $X^{1/2}$?

I know that I can use the Jacobian formula since $\sqrt{\cdot}: (0,\infty) \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ is bijective and thus invertible and so on... Such that it satisfies The conditions of the Theorem. Then I get the probability density function 
$$f_{X^{1/2}}(u) = K u^{n-1} e^{-u^2/2}$$
with $K \in \mathbb{R}$, but only for $u \in (0,\infty)$. How do I then determine the probability density function in the Interval $(-\infty,0]$ ? Intuitively I would say that it is zero there, since the probability density function $f_X$ of $X$ is $0$ since $X$ is $\chi^2$ distributed. But how do I know for sure? How can I show this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Remember the basics: $f: X \rightarrow Y$, so to the probability of $y \in Y$ is equal to the sum of the probabilities of all those $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$.

Comment: What is your $K$?

Comment: $\frac{2}{2^{n/2} \Gamma(n/2)}$

Comment: This is not the correct K for Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(df=n)$ then its PDF is $0$ on $(-\infty,0).$
The square root transformation maps $(0,\infty)$ to itself. 
(Notice that if $X$ had negative values, you couldn't use the square
root transformation for those negative values.)
So  $Y = X^{1/2}$ also has support $(0,\infty)$ and its PDF is also
$0$ on $(-\infty,0).$

**Addendum.** Here is a demo for 5 df using R statistical software:
Generate 100,000 values of $X,$ square them to get $Y$'s, make a
histogram of the $Y$'s, plot the PDF of $Y$ through the histogram
to see if it fits. (With the correct $K$ for the PDF of $Y,$ it does.)

```
m = 10^5;  x = rchisq(m, 5); y = sqrt(x)
hist(y, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", ylim=c(0,.6))
k = 1/(2^(5/2-1)*gamma(5/2))
yy = seq(0, 6, by=.001); pdfy = k*yy^4*exp(-yy^2/2)
lines(yy, pdfy, type="l", lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Ok so one could argue by Definition of the transformation that it has to be $0$ on $(-\infty,0)$ right? Such that the whole transformation would be $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $x \mapsto 0$ for $x \leq 0$ and $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ for $x>0$?

Comment: No. You start and end with $(0, \infty).$. Once more, what is your $K$.?

Comment: It is $K= \frac{2}{2^{n/2} \Gamma(n/2)}$. Ok I think I get it now why it has to be zero. In the Theorem one maps from an open set $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X \in S)=1$. So it has to bero on $(-\infty,0). Am I right this time? :)

Comment: That's the $K$ for X ~ CHISQ(n). Are you sure it's the same for Y? And yes, $P(X > 0) = P(Y > 0) = 1.$ // Similarly, if $X$ ~ UNIF(0,1), then $Y = \sqrt{X}$ has a BETA distribution on (0,1). Here $P(0 < X < 1) = P(0< Y < 1) = 1.$ // In general, the first step in doing a transformation of a probability dist'n is to identify the support before and after transformation. Doing that helps avoid a large proportion of beginners mistakes.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [_this page_](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/ChisquareChi.pdf). See my Addendum.